# MySQL does not identify character '?' on select

Tags: mysql, database, select, character-encoding

I got a table in MySQL with the following columns:

```
id     name   email    address   borningDate
```

I have a form in a HTML page that submits this data to a servlet, responsible for saving it at the database. Due to charset issues (already fixed), I saved a row like this, when trying to store letters with accents:

```
19        ?        ?       ?      2015-03-01
```

and now I want to delete this row.

Yeah, doing this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id=19;
```

works nice. My didatic question is: why, if I try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE name='?';
```

it returns  `0 rows affected`, like if it can't see `?` as a valid character?

Comment: `SELECT HEX(name), name FROM table WHERE ...` -- so we can see what is in the field.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't whitespace inside the field too?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
SELECT id, HEX(name), HEX(email), HEX(address), borningDate FROM table
```

This will tell you what's actually in the database. It probably isn't actually ASCII question marks. The question marks are probably substitution characters applied when MySQL tries to convert the column's character set to the connection's character set.

To manage this more specifically, do `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` and look for the character set being used for the text columns. This probably shows up at the end of the table definition as something like `DEFAULT CHARSET utf8` or some such thing. But it might be specified in the column definition.

Once you know the character set, issue the command `SET NAMES charset`, for example, `SET NAMES utf8`.  Then reissue your commands and see if you get better results than the `?` substitution character. That assumes, of course, that the client program you are using can handle the character set mentioned.

Comment: `SET NAMES charset` must match the client character set, not the table character set. So the second part of the answer is simply incorrect.

Comment: @zerkms  Not exactly. This is a troubleshooting technique. I'm not proposing to go into production with this character set choice.

Comment: "This is a troubleshooting technique." --- you cannot troubleshoot with random unpredictable steps. The result of `SET NAMES table_character_set` is unpredictable for an arbitrary combination of a table and a client. I honestly cannot believe someone could suggest doing that seriously. The correct solution for that would be to see how the data was inserted - that way you would know for sure what has happened (and how exactly data was broken). That's right - that would be the trustworthy information gained in minutes. But hey, it's not fun to do something that works is it? :-D